# Xdebug is installed but does not seem to be working with PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I downloaded Xdebug and it seems to be installed, my `phpinfo()` has Xdebug in it and the settings are as follows:

[image: phpinfo() xdebug settings 1/1]
[phpinfo() xdebug settings 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7OSg.png)

I have tried adding a parameter `http://localhost/test.php?XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM`, and using the Xdebug Chrome extension to change the IDE KEY in phpinfo() but I still cant get Xdebug to trigger.

PhpStorm is listening on port 9000 and I've confirmed this using `lsof -i :9000` and Xdebug is also connecting to localhost 9000 according to phpinfo().

I can't figure out why Xdebug isn't connecting to PhpStorm. Any help is appreciated if you need any more info let me know.

Edit:
I tried to send my xdebug debug info to a log file but the log file is empty when I browse to the php page. I know error logging is correctly setup since the path to the log file shows up in phpinfo().

Edit:
I changed the location of my debug log and here is the output dump from it for one request:

```
[21595] Log opened at 2019-11-27 15:57:20
[21595] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[21595] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[21595] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[21595] I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9000.
[21595] W: Creating socket for '::1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
[21595] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[21595] Log closed at 2019-11-27 15:57:20
```

Comment: Enable xdebug log and provide it here for such unsuccessful debug attempt. It will tell if Xdebug tries to connect and what the response is.

Comment: do i do this by setting `xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"`?

Comment: 1) Yes, `xdebug.remote_log` option. 2) If it's empty -- then Xdebug does not see "Debug me" flag. Show your whole Xdebug section (from `phpinfo()`).

Comment: The URL parameter is wrong, please replace `XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM` with `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` please read more here https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I tried `Xdebug_SeSSION_START=PHPSTORM` and it shows no changes :(

Comment: @LazyOne ive updated the post to show all of the xdebug info from phpinfo()

Comment: 1) I see you have `~/Documents...` path for the log -- it's possible that Xdebug is unable to write there. Try specifying an absolute path in a place where it can write for sure (`/var/tmp/xdebug.log` or alike). 2) You have autostart option enabled, so it should try to debug every single request. Need to see xdebug log for sure. 3) You can still try adding `xdebug_break();` in your code to see if it make any difference. 4) I also suggest to change xdebug port to 9001 or some another in both php.ini and IDE (to avoid any collisions with possible php-fpm that you have)

Comment: 5) You have `remote_connect_back` option enabled ... which ignores `remote_host` option. It usually picks up the right IP anyway, but better be sure (will see from xdebug log what exactly it tries to use). 6) Better to use IPv4 addresses (i.e. `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`) as on some systems the IPv6 may take over and it may not work so well with that.

Comment: @LazyOne 1) changing the log file location DID let xdebug write to a log. this is the dump from that log
`[21595] Log opened at 2019-11-27 15:57:20
[21595] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[21595] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[21595] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[21595] I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9000.
[21595] W: Creating socket for '::1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
[21595] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[21595] Log closed at 2019-11-27 15:57:20`

Comment: So do #5 and #6 and check again.

Comment: Implementing 4, 5, and 6 seems to have worked. changing the ports to 9001 and remove `remote_connect_back` seemed to solve the issue. I am still not sure why changing the ports solved the issue since according to lsof the only thing listening on port 9000 was phpstorm

Comment: 1) Autodetected `::1` means localhost in IPv6. This means that IPv6 has priority on your system over IPv4. By doing #5 and #6 you have ensured that IPv4 is now used for Xdebug communications (I'm not sure if Xdebug (or PhpStorm) properly supports IPv6 here -- Xdebug shoudl support it from v2.5 .. but I see some ticket from May 2016 where it still does not work although PhpStorm listens that port on IPv6). 2) If PhpStorm was the only app listening on 9000 then it should have worked, really. Maybe it's a firewall? if you want -- revert back to 9000 and try again.

Comment: Reverting back to 9000 still works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to enable and collect Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session. In case if it stays empty, make sure that anyone can write into that file, not just current user (plus do not use relative paths or `~`). Such log will tell what is going on and will provide clues on what to look at after that.

Other things:

- You have `xdebug.remote_connect_back` option enabled ... which ignores value set with `xdebug.remote_host`. It usually picks up the right IP anyway, but better be sure here (Xdebug log will tell what exactly it detects).
- Better to use IPv4 addresses (i.e. `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`) as on some systems the IPv6 has priority over IPv4 and Xdebug (or PhpStorm) having some issues with IPv6 (at very least on some systems).
- It also makes sense to use port 9001 or some another instead of default 9000 as php-fpm also uses that port by default and you may have it installed at some point.

Comment: remote_connect_back was replaced with discover_client_host

Comment: @AlxVallejo Sure. In Xdebug **v3**. But the author in this question uses Xdebug **v2**. Anyway, for those who uses Xdebug v3 now but sees answers/configs for v2 -- check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide